# Suspended delete query with wait type = PAGEIOLATCH_EX

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

I have a delete query that has been running for a full day now with the above status - can anyone advise with this?

```
(@P1 int)DELETE FROM ZQV_F_GL2CD 
WHERE M_ID = @P1
```

Apologies if my question is vague - never really ran into an issue like this before..

Comment: Tag the dbms used. (That code is product specific.)

Comment: Problems with disk subsystem leads to this wait type

Comment: Do you have any tables pointing with a foreign key to this table. If so, try creating an index on foreign key column.

Answer (score 1):

Wait types of `PAGEIOLATCH` indicate that it is fetching pages off disk.

If there is lots of data or pages to fetch then this can take a long time to process but it can still be deleting.

I recently ran into this deleting large `Image` data types from a table. However this did not take a full day but could take up to 5 minutes just to delete 5 rows. So if there were many more rows then it could be conceivable that it could take a full day.

This was also compounded by the `tempdb` being incredibly large due to the use of `implict transactions` and also running low on disk space.

I have solved this by chunking the deletes further using this process I found [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes).

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @r INT;
SET @r = 1;
WHILE @r > 0
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
        DELETE TOP (100000) -- this will change
           dbo.SalesOrderDetailEnlarged
           WHERE ProductID IN (712, 870, 873);

          SET @r = @@ROWCOUNT;

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
  -- CHECKPOINT;    -- if simple
  -- BACKUP LOG ... -- if full
END
```